# Por que "contains" com bytes negativos precisa de "cast" no Java 8?

Tags: java, arraylist, int, byte

Se eu fizer `if(list.contains(-106))`
e essa `list` é uma `ArrayList` de `bytes` que tem o valor `-106`,
o método `contains` vai retorna `false`.

Para eu ter o resultado correto preciso fazer *cast* explícito do `-106` para um `byte`, por que isso acontece?

Tem algo a ver com o Java entender esse `byte` como um `int`? No fim tanto `byte` como `int` não são apenas ranges numéricos, onde a única diferença é o intervalo do valor que cada um guarda?

```
ArrayList<Byte> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add((byte) -106);
if (x.contains(-106))
    System.out.println(2);
```

Isso pode ser considerado algum tipo de problema? Descobrir que o motivo é que o Java trata o `-106` como um `int` por padrão e quando você usa ele no `contains` isso é convertido para `Integer` que retorna `false` em seu `equals` caso o elemento comparado não seja um `Integer`.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

O que ocasiona nesse problema? Isso poderia ser considerado uma falha na estrutura do Java ou algo do tipo ou isso é algo meio óbvio ou que está certo? Falo tanto de como eles faz essas comparações de como o `contains` recebe qualquer objeto e do Java tratar qualquer número como um inteiro a não ser que você especifique com um *cast* ou um `L` ou guarde em uma variável.

Answer (score 6):

Primeiramente, não tem nada a ver com o fato de usar valores negativos. Mas vamos por partes.

---

O método `contains` recebe um `Object`, podemos ver na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) que a assinatura dele é:

```java
public boolean contains(Object o)
```

E quando usamos um valor primitivo em um contexto que precisa de um objeto, ele é automaticamente convertido para o respectivo *wrapper*, em um processo conhecido como [*autoboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Para exemplificar, vamos criar um método que recebe um `Object` e ver o que acontece quando passamos primitivos diferentes para ele:

```java
static void f(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj +  ", tipo=" + obj.getClass());
}
```

Se chamarmos o método assim:

```java
f(-106);
f((byte) -106);
```

A saída será:

```
-106, tipo=class java.lang.Integer
-106, tipo=class java.lang.Byte
```

Isso porque, por padrão, [um literal numérico é `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), por isso ao passar `-106`, foi feito o *autoboxing* para `Integer`. Mas quando é feito o *cast* para `byte`, o *autoboxing* converte para `Byte`.

E como já dito no início, não tem nada a ver com o fato dos valores serem negativos. Com números positivos isso também acontece:

```java
f(106);        // 106, tipo=class java.lang.Integer
f((byte) 106); // 106, tipo=class java.lang.Byte
```

---

Ou seja, sua lista contém uma instância de `Byte`, como podemos verificar facilmente:

```java
ArrayList<Byte> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add((byte) -106);
System.out.println(x.get(0).getClass()); // class java.lang.Byte
```

Já o método `contains` compara os objetos usando o método `equals` (cada elemento da lista é comparado com o objeto passado).

E segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), o método `equals` da classe `Byte` só retorna `true` se o objeto passado for uma instância de `Byte` com o mesmo valor. Exemplo:

```java
Byte b = Byte.valueOf("-106");
System.out.println(b.equals(Integer.valueOf("-106"))); // false
System.out.println(b.equals(Byte.valueOf("-106"))); // true
```

O mesmo vale para a classe `Integer`, cuja [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) diz que o método `equals` só retorna `true` se o outro objeto for uma instância de `Integer` com o mesmo valor numérico.

Ou seja, mesmo que o valor numérico seja idêntico, o método `equals` só retorna `true` se ambos os objetos forem do mesmo tipo (ou ambos `Integer`, ou ambos `Byte`).

Por isso que ao buscar por `-106` ele não é encontrado, já que no fundo estamos procurando por uma instância de `Integer` em uma lista que contém instâncias de `Byte`. A busca só funciona se fizermos o *cast* (ou seja, `(byte) -106`), pois aí estaremos buscando por uma instância de `Byte`.

E novamente, isso vale tanto para valores positivos quanto negativos. O sinal não faz diferença, e sim o tipo do *wrapper* para o qual o primitivo é convertido.

---

Quanto a estar "certo" ou ser uma "falha", é discutível. Os criadores da linguagem decidiram que os *wrappers* seriam restritivos quanto ao tipo, e essas são as consequências com as quais temos que conviver. Talvez eles não tenham pensado nisso, ou talvez pensaram e concluíram que seria aceitável, mas de qualquer forma não achei referências sobre isso. Enfim, *design* de linguagens é mais difícil do que as pessoas pensam...

Talvez já fuja do escopo da pergunta, mas enfim, se quiser que a busca se comporte diferente do padrão (por exemplo, recebendo qualquer tipo e considerando apenas o valor numérico, independente do tipo), o jeito é você mesmo implementar sua própria lógica. Por exemplo:

```java
static boolean contains(List<Byte> list, Number search) {
    int n = search.byteValue(); // força que o valor seja byte
    // só coloquei esse print como curiosidade, para vermos o tipo sendo passado
    System.out.println("procurando por " + search + " -> " + search.getClass());
    for (byte b : list) { // loop com unboxing
        if (b == n) { // compara os valores como o primitivo byte
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Agora não importa o valor numérico passado, este sempre será convertido para `byte` e comparado com o respectivo valor primitivo dos elementos da lista:

```java
List<Byte> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add((byte) -106);

// busca funciona sem cast
System.out.println(contains(x, -106)); // true

// e mesmo se o tipo for outro, continua funcionando
System.out.println(contains(x, (long) -106)); // true
System.out.println(contains(x, (double) -106)); // true
```

A saída será:

```
procurando por -106 -> class java.lang.Integer
true
procurando por -106 -> class java.lang.Long
true
procurando por -106.0 -> class java.lang.Double
true
```

Só não sei se vale a pena toda essa volta, acho bem mais simples fazer um *cast* no parâmetro.